# Watermark usage in push notification of EWS(java)

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

Could anyone please elaborate a bit on watermark and its use with respect to recreating subscription using push notification in EWS application?

I read the Microsoft provided information regarding it. But I did not get to understand accurately its usage.

It is explained as:
"The Watermark element represents an event bookmark in the mailbox event queue."

Does it mean that for every event we get new or different watermark in the notification?

Also: 
"If a Subscribe request contains a watermark, the subscription is created from the watermark forward."

Does it mean that if we subscribe using a watermark previously sent to us, we can get or identify all the events occurred after it?

Answer (score 0):

> > Does it mean that for every event we get new or different watermark in the notification?

Yes as the Events are delivered to you client you will get the Water-Mark associated for that event in the Queue.

> > Does it mean that if we subscribe using a watermark previously sent to us, we can get or identify all the events occurred after it?

Yes if you use a previous watermark your client is telling the server to send the events that occurred after that watermark. Watermarks are valid for 30 days but there are events that can trigger them to become invalid eg 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2008/07/24/transitioning-to-exchange-web-services-notifications/ . So you need to consider that if you using them for synchronisation.

Comment: Thanks Glen for the help.